# How do I call a function AFTER my Collections.sort is done?

Tags: java, android, sorting, listview

I have a sorting method but it's not allowing me to call the refresh method.

I get an error: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

Here is my method

```
private void sort(final String field){
    Log.d(TAG, "Sorting on " + field);

    if(GACommuter.rideMatches != null) {

        Collections.sort(GACommuter.rideMatches, new Comparator<Ride>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Ride ride1, Ride ride2) {
                switch (field) {
                    case "home":
                        return ride1.getDistanceFromHome().compareTo(ride2.getDistanceFromHome());
                    default:
                        return ride1.getDistanceFromWork().compareTo(ride2.getDistanceFromWork());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    refreshListView();
}
```

My refreshListView method simply updates the visible items in my ListView.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace associated with your crash. Also, where are you calling `sort()`?

Comment: Post the full error here, including the stack trace.  Post the code that calls this as well.  Your code for refreshing after a sort is fine, your problem is in something else.

Comment: You may be experiencing garbage collection, is everything instantiated correctly?

Comment: I believe the problem was in fact that I was calling sort before the list was completed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you call sort when a list view item is clicked, so there is a clash.

What you may consider is using PostDelayed instead of just calling refreshListView:

```
 listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { refreshListView(); }
 }, 100);
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll give that a try.